# removing an important style tag from a media query

Tags: javascript, salesforce, pardot

What's the javascript code to change the style to this?

```
`@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
.contentpageDefaultLandingPageTemplate .contentRoot {
    width: 320px !important;
}
`
```

I want to make it as width: 100% !important.

Comment: you're going to need to share some more information about what you're doing, this doesn't quite make sense. what does the relevant piece of html look like? do you have any existing js that you've tried? is this existing css inline, or inserted by js, or external...?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking about the javascript implementation of the CSS code. If that's the case, below is the javascript for the CSS

```
const rootElement = document.querySelector('.contentpageDefaultLandingPageTemplate .contentRoot');

if (window.innerWidth <= 480) {
  rootElement.style.width = '320px';
}
```